# Cannot trigger click on element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some element in a web page that I want to simulate a click on. Other elements in the same page can be easily clicked by the following logic:

```
$('.someClass').trigger('click');
```

But if I try this with a specific element, it doesn't work.
I tried to add a click handler to the element that cannot be clicked, to see if the reverse was possible=*Catching the a click instead of triggering one*:

```
$('.someClass').on('click', function (event) {
   console.log('element was clicked');
});
```

It worked. This means: The selector is correct and the element exists in the DOM. But why has my click no effect?

I tried the following all without no success:

**Clicking the position where the element is located:**

```
function simulateClick(x, y) {
    $(document.elementFromPoint(x, y)).click();
}

var element = $('.someClass')[0];
var bodyRect = document.body.getBoundingClientRect(),
    elemRect = element.getBoundingClientRect(),
    voffset   = elemRect.top - bodyRect.top;
    hoffset = elemRect.left - bodyRect.left;

console.log('Element is ' + voffset + ' vertical pixels from <body>');
console.log('Element is ' + hoffset + ' horizontal pixels from <body>');
simulateClick(hoffset, voffset);
```

**First unbinding from all events:**

```
$('.someClass').unbind();
$('.someClass').trigger('click');
```

**Using vanilla JS to click:**

```
$('.someClass')[0].click();
```

It's obvious to me that the page somehow **blocks and prevents all clicks on this element**, but how can I find the mechanism which is responsible for that? The site uses obfuscated JS and I have no idea how to circumvent it?

Any ideas? (The client side is in my realm after all^^)

Comment: if you cant click it then it could mean it's not clickable, as in no event listener is attached to it.

Comment: 10$ says it has `pointer-events: none` set on it.

Comment: What you mean be simulate click on it ? *I tried to add a click handler* when you trigger an element you just execute whatever you passed to the click() or on("click",..), is that what you want?

Comment: May be the element you are trying to click is behind another layer, try inspect element

Comment: So you are saying that triggering `click` doesn't work, but attaching a handler to it and then clicking on the element works? Well in that case... it must be because there's no handler attached to said event. Also, catching the event is not the reverse of triggering the event.

Comment: I just want to simulate a mouse click on the element. I don't care if there is already a event listener on the element. I added one to demonstrate that the element was selected correctly and it does exist (to prevent questions in this direction). I don't want to add my own click event handler. that works. I want to simulate a click as if i clicked it with my physical mouse.

Comment: @MinusFour: Then how can I click on this element as if I would when using the mouse? The mouse also doesn't care whether an element is attacked to some place on the screen.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: How can I check this? I use Firebug and I tried to inspect the element and looked under the *DOM* and *Events* Tab. Couldn't see anything.

Comment: @NikolaiTschacher what kind of element is it?

Comment: @NikolaiTschacher listeners are actions to do once the event has been emitted. When you trigger the event (be it through javascript or with the UI) your listeners are called. If there's no listeners, nothing is done. There are default listeners for some elements though.

Answer (score 0):

The event is probably not bound via jquery, but on the element. I'm not sure how that is, but this didn't work for me:

```
$('.mycls:eq(0)').trigger('click');
```

but this did:

```
document.querySelector('.mycls').click();
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a click handler to the elements that you want to simulate a click on.

```
$('.myelementsclass').bind('click', function() { 
    alert($(this)) 
});
```

Then use your logic to trigger the click:

```
$('.myelementsclass').trigger('click');
```